Pooling Model Results with Rubin's Rule for Multiple Responses (Same Predictors, Different Outcomes)
I understand that Rubin's rule is commonly applied for pooling model results across multiple imputed datasets, where the same set of predictors and response are used, like this:
glmmTMB(varY ~ varA + varB + varC, data=imp1, truncated_nbinom2)
glmmTMB(varY ~ varA + varB + varC, data=imp2, truncated_nbinom2)
glmmTMB(varY ~ varA + varB + varC, data=imp3, truncated_nbinom2)

However, I have a slightly different scenario. I have an imputed dataset, but instead of building models with the same response variable across imputed datasets, I have built several models with different response variables but the same predictors from the same imputed dataset, like this:
glmmTMB(varY1 ~ varA + varB + varC, data=imp, truncated_nbinom2)
glmmTMB(varY2 ~ varA + varB + varC, data=imp, truncated_nbinom2)
glmmTMB(varY3 ~ varA + varB + varC, data=imp, truncated_nbinom2)

The glmmTMB R package currently does not allow for fitting a multivariate model (i.e., with multiple response variables in a single model), so I had to run individual models for each response variable.
My question is:

Can I apply Rubin's rule in this case to pool the results of these models even though the response variables are different but the predictors are the same?
If Rubin's rule isn't suitable, is there another way to pool the results and obtain a single set of model coefficients and standard errors?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

How come the random-forest tag is relevant to this?

@user11852 I used random forest for imputing the dataset
